# Windows regkey RunOnce an exe with a space in the name

Tags: windows, windows-registry

I have an exe with a space in it, let's say `C:\an exe.exe`. I want to run this once with the [RunOnce](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/setupapi/run-and-runonce-registry-keys) reg key. However, I cannot get it to work because of the space in the name. Whatever combination of quotes or spaces I attempt, it does not execute. Is it possible to make this work?

Comment: Add quotes around it like this: `"C:\an exe.exe"`.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 That didn't work.

Comment: You might try Windows 8.3 filename, if enabled. See https://digitalsupport.ge.com/en_US/Article/Is-Windows-8-3-File-Naming-Enabled-How-Do-I-Enable-8-3-File-Naming-If-It-Is-Not . For example, "Alongfilename.txt" has a pseudonym, "alongf~1.txt".

Comment: Are you modeling your entry after those found unnder the adjacent `Run` key? Not trying to assign your executable path to the `(Default)` value of `RunOnce`, are you? You know if you're using environmental variables in your path your data has to be of type `REG_EXPAND_SZ`, right? A screenshot of the registry or a `.reg` export posted in a code block added to your question may help.

Comment: @KeithMiller Looks like that may be the answer! Though it appears to be blocking the rest of Windows startup which I didn't expect. But it _is_ now executing the exe on startup.